# Python count up by 5 after each iteration in for loop

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I am trying to open a csv file in python and read the rows into a list.

The list is then sent to a function where I want to add 5 to the value of x after each iteration with the value of d going up by 10 after every 10th iteration.

d I have working but can't quite figure out x. Please can someone help me understand where I am going wrong with my math. I thought setting x = 0 outside the loop and then x+=5 inside would do it.

```
results = []
with open('file.csv', newline='') as inputfile:
    for row in csv.reader(inputfile):
        results.append(row[0]) # 24 rows in csv file

def buildcount(listGroup, z):
    listGroup = listGroup
    z = z
    x = 0
    for i in range (0, len(listGroup))
        print(i)
        d = 10*(i // 10 + z)
        x +=5
        print(x) 
        if i % 10 == 0:
            x = 0
    return i

z = 10
mainInput = results
buildcount(mainInput)



#current output of x
5
5
10
15
20
25
30
35
40
45
5
10
15
20
25
30
35
40
45
5
10
15
20
25


#desired output of x
0
5
10
15
20
25
30
35
40
45
0
5
10
15
20
25
30
35
40
45
0
5
10
15
```

Comment: What is `z` for?

Comment: z sets the value of d which counts by 10 for every 10th loop, I don't have any problems with that so left it out the print.

Comment: So `d` should be 0 for the first 10 rows, then 10 for the next 10, then 20 etc.?

Comment: Correct Nick I would like to count up by 5 for x in the lots of 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're looking for some fairly simple math on the loop counter:

```py
def buildcount(listGroup):
    for i in range (0, len(listGroup)):
        x = (i % 10) * 5
        d = (i // 10) * 10
        print(f'i={i}, x={x}, d={d}')
    return i
```

Output (for a 24-entry `listGroup`):

```
i=0, x=0, d=0
i=1, x=5, d=0
i=2, x=10, d=0
i=3, x=15, d=0
i=4, x=20, d=0
i=5, x=25, d=0
i=6, x=30, d=0
i=7, x=35, d=0
i=8, x=40, d=0
i=9, x=45, d=0
i=10, x=0, d=10
i=11, x=5, d=10
i=12, x=10, d=10
i=13, x=15, d=10
i=14, x=20, d=10
i=15, x=25, d=10
i=16, x=30, d=10
i=17, x=35, d=10
i=18, x=40, d=10
i=19, x=45, d=10
i=20, x=0, d=20
i=21, x=5, d=20
i=22, x=10, d=20
i=23, x=15, d=20
```

Comment: No worries - I think you should be able to replace `10` with `z` quite easily to change your grouping

Comment: Already done it. Works perfectly and much more elegant. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want `x` to reset after 50 and then increment d after reaching multiples of ten.  This uses mod (`%`) for the first, and just integer division for the second.

```
x = 0
d = 0
for i in range(21):
    x = i*5 % 50
    d = int(i/10) * 10
    print(f'{i=} {x=} {d=}')
```

returns

```
i=0 x=0 d=0
i=1 x=5 d=0
i=2 x=10 d=0
i=3 x=15 d=0
i=4 x=20 d=0
i=5 x=25 d=0
i=6 x=30 d=0
i=7 x=35 d=0
i=8 x=40 d=0
i=9 x=45 d=0
i=10 x=0 d=10
i=11 x=5 d=10
i=12 x=10 d=10
i=13 x=15 d=10
i=14 x=20 d=10
i=15 x=25 d=10
i=16 x=30 d=10
i=17 x=35 d=10
i=18 x=40 d=10
i=19 x=45 d=10
i=20 x=0 d=20
```

Comment: The original answer was based on the original question.  This answer matches the expectations now.